# Puppeteer html to pdf - Not Getting desired content padding-bottom

Tags: html, css, puppeteer

I'm working on converting an HTML document to a PDF using the Puppeteer library in Node.js. The HTML structure consists of a two-part resume (left and right sections).

I want the left section's background color to extend to the edge of the page (i.e., margin of 0), while ensuring that both the left and right sections' content/text have padding at the bottom.

I've experimented with setting an image as the background and various @page settings, but haven't achieved the desired result.

Could someone guide me on how to accomplish this?

Here's the HTML code I'm working with:

```css
@page {
        size: A4;
        padding-bottom: 20px;

        @bottom-right {
            content: element(footer);
        }
        background: url('https://e1.pxfuel.com/desktop-wallpaper/271/821/desktop-wallpaper-cv-backgrounds-cv.jpg');
    }

    @media print {
        .pageInit {
            margin: 0px auto;
        }
    }

    /*! CSS Used from: http://127.0.0.1:5500/resume.css */
    .resumecontainer {
        position: relative;
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    .pageInit {
        margin: 30px auto;
        width: 210mm;
        min-height: 297mm;
        position: relative;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: white;
        /* padding: 40px; */
    }

    .pageInit section {
        break-inside: avoid;
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }

    @media print {
        body {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        #resumeContainer {
            visibility: visible;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        .pageInit {
            margin: auto;
            box-shadow: none;
            padding: 0;
        }
    }

    /*! CSS Used from: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css */
    *,
    ::after,
    ::before {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family);
        font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size);
        font-weight: var(--bs-body-font-weight);
        line-height: var(--bs-body-line-height);
        color: var(--bs-body-color);
        text-align: var(--bs-body-text-align);
        background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    }

    h1,
    h2,
    h3 {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: .5rem;
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 1.2;
        color: var(--bs-heading-color);
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: calc(1.375rem + 1.5vw);
    }


    h2 {
        font-size: calc(1.325rem + .9vw);
    }


    h3 {
        font-size: calc(1.3rem + .6vw);
    }

    p {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    ul {
        padding-left: 2rem;
    }

    ul {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    strong {
        font-weight: bolder;
    }

    img {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .list-unstyled {
        padding-left: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .clearfix::after {
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        content: "";
    }

    .d-flex {
        display: flex !important;
    }

    .position-relative {
        position: relative !important;
    }

    .flex-column {
        flex-direction: column !important;
    }

    .justify-content-center {
        justify-content: center !important;
    }

    .my-4 {
        margin-top: 1.5rem !important;
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem !important;
    }

    .mb-1 {
        margin-bottom: .25rem !important;
    }

    .mb-2 {
        margin-bottom: .5rem !important;
    }

    .px-3 {
        padding-right: 1rem !important;
        padding-left: 1rem !important;
    }

    .py-1 {
        padding-top: .25rem !important;
        padding-bottom: .25rem !important;
    }

    .pb-1 {
        padding-bottom: .25rem !important;
    }

    .pb-5 {
        padding-bottom: 3rem !important;
    }

    .fw-bold {
        font-weight: 700 !important;
    }

    .text-uppercase {
        text-transform: uppercase !important;
    }

    /*! CSS Used from: Embedded */
    .leftbox {
        background-color: #3d3e42;
        color: white;
    }

    .pageInit {
        padding: 0px;
        min-height: auto;
    }

    .rightbox {
        padding: 30px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .clearfix::after,
    .clearfix::before {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }

    .clearfix::after {
        clear: both;
    }

    .resume-section-title {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        position: relative;
        color: #434e5e;
    }

    .resume-section-title:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1.5px;
        background: #8d9aad;
    }

    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    article {
        display: block;
    }

    h3 {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }

    p {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    ul {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    h3 {
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 1.2;
        color: inherit;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 1.75rem;
    }

    .d-flex {
        display: flex !important;
    }

    .flex-column {
        flex-direction: column !important;
    }

    .position-relative {
        position: relative !important;
    }

    .mb-1 {
        margin-bottom: 0.25rem !important;
    }

    .mb-2 {
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem !important;
    }

    .pb-5 {
        padding-bottom: 1rem !important;
    }

    .ml-auto {
        margin-left: auto !important;
    }

    .font-weight-bold {
        font-weight: 700 !important;
    }

    .resume-section-content {
        color: #58677c;
    }

    .resume-timeline {
        padding-left: 2rem;
    }

    .resume-timeline:before {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 3px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #aab4c3;
        left: 6px;
        top: 4px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .resume-timeline-item:before {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: -32px;
        top: 3px;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        border: 4px solid #58677c;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .resume-company-name {
        color: #58677c;
        font-size: 0.875rem;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .resume-position-time {
        font-size: 0.875rem;
        color: #aab4c3;
    }

    .resume-position-title {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        color: #434e5e;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Multipurpose Resume Template</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </link>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="resumecontainer" id="resumeContainer">
        <div class="pageInit">
            <div id="resumeviewFrame">

                <div class="container1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4 leftbox">
                            <section class="profile section-padding" style="margin-top: 40px;padding: 20px;">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="picture-resume-wrapper-0" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                        <div class="picture-resume d-flex justify-content-center">
                                            <img class="rounded-circle"
                                                src="https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_profile_original,q_auto,f_auto/profile/photos/3864710/original/isurunix.png"
                                                alt="" width="80%">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <h2 class="resume-section-title text-uppercase font-weight-bold pb-1"
                                        style="color: white;">
                                        Contact
                                    </h2>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12 py-1">
                                            <span><strong>Call</strong><br />+34 123 456 789</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 py-1">
                                            <span><strong>Email</strong><br />j.anderson@gmail.com</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 py-1">
                                            <span><strong>Website</strong><br />janderson.com</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 py-1">
                                            <span><strong>Home</strong><br />Los Angeles, CA</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="my-4"></div>
                                    <h2 class="resume-section-title text-uppercase font-weight-bold pb-1"
                                        style="color: white;">
                                        Education
                                    </h2>
                                    <div class="resume-section-content" style="color: white;">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li class="mb-2">
                                                <div class="fw-bold">
                                                    Philosophy
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="resume-degree-org">Undergraduate - University XAV</div>
                                                <div class="resume-degree-time">2015 — 2019</div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="fw-bold">
                                                    Culturology
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="resume-degree-org">Master's Degree - HSE</div>
                                                <div class="resume-degree-time">2019 — 2021</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="my-4"></div>
                                    <h2 class="resume-section-title text-uppercase font-weight-bold pb-1"
                                        style="color: white;">
                                        Skills
                                    </h2>
                                    <ul class="col-12" style="padding-left: 15px;">
                                        <li>Html</li>
                                        <li>Java</li>
                                        <li>NodeJs</li>
                                        <li>Comunication</li>
                                        <li>Leadership</li>
                                    </ul>

                                    <div class="my-4"></div>
                                    <h2 class="resume-section-title text-uppercase font-weight-bold pb-1"
                                        style="color: white;">
                                        Languge
                                    </h2>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-12">
                                        <li>English</li>
                                        <li>French</li>
                                    </ul>




                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <div class="rightbox">
                                <div class="name-wrapper">
                                    <h1>John Anderson</h1><!-- YOUR NAME AND LAST NAME  -->
                                </div>

                                <div class="contact-presentation" style="color: #58677c">
                                    <!-- YOUR PRESENTATION RESUME  -->
                                    <p><span class="bold">Lorem</span> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                                        elit. Vivamus euismod congue nisi, nec consequat quam. In consectetur faucibus
                                        turpis eget laoreet. Sed nec imperdiet purus. </p>
                                </div>

                                <h2 class="resume-section-title text-uppercase font-weight-bold pb-1">
                                    Work Experience
                                </h2>

                                <div class="resume-section-content">
                                    <div class="resume-timeline position-relative">
                                        <article class="resume-timeline-item position-relative pb-5">
                                            <div class="resume-timeline-item-header mb-2">
                                                <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">
                                                    <h3 class="resume-position-title font-weight-bold mb-1">
                                                        Editor
                                                    </h3>
                                                    <div class="resume-company-name ml-auto">
                                                        GC Osnova
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="resume-position-time">2018 — 2019</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--//resume-timeline-item-header-->
                                            <div class="resume-timeline-item-desc">
                                                <p>
                                                    I do everything related to social networks and texts. I write
                                                    newsletters and posts. I create landing pages, translate press
                                                    releases,
                                                    do special projects.
                                                </p>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        Funny pre-revolutionary magazines
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        Funny pre-revolutionary magazines
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        Funny pre-revolutionary magazines
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </article>

                                        <article class="resume-timeline-item position-relative pb-5">
                                            <div class="resume-timeline-item-header mb-2">
                                                <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">
                                                    <h3 class="resume-position-title font-weight-bold mb-1">
                                                        Copywriter
                                                    </h3>
                                                    <div class="resume-company-name ml-auto">
                                                        Texterra
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="resume-position-time">2018 — 2019</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="resume-timeline-item-desc">
                                                <p>
                                                    Wrote a lot of texts, figured out a bunch of topics. Now I'm not
                                                    afraid
                                                    of SEO keywords and I do a vanity
                                                    search to order.
                                                </p>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        How to prosthetic teeth
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        Description line 2
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        Description line 3
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </article>
                                        <article class="resume-timeline-item position-relative pb-5">
                                            <div class="resume-timeline-item-header mb-2">
                                                <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">
                                                    <h3 class="resume-position-title font-weight-bold mb-1">
                                                        Author
                                                    </h3>
                                                    <div class="resume-company-name ml-auto">
                                                        Company Name
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="resume-position-time">2019</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="resume-timeline-item-desc">
                                                <p>
                                                    I took three interviews and wrote a text based on them for the
                                                    Mail.ru
                                                    blog.
                                                </p>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        Machine learning for trading
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </article>
                                        <article class="resume-timeline-item position-relative">
                                            <div class="resume-timeline-item-header mb-2">
                                                <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">
                                                    <h3 class="resume-position-title font-weight-bold mb-1">
                                                        SММ
                                                    </h3>
                                                    <div class="resume-company-name ml-auto">
                                                        Company
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="resume-position-time">2015 — 2019</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="resume-timeline-item-desc">
                                                <p>
                                                    Managed the Telegram channel, taught interns to write funny posts,
                                                    drew
                                                    pictures and made live reports in one studio media. Wrote
                                                    collections,
                                                    reviews and translated materials for a university academic journal
                                                    in
                                                    another
                                                </p>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        Report from the Student Council meeting
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        Report from the Student Council meeting
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        Report from the Student Council meeting
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        Report from the Student Council meeting
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        Report from the Student Council meeting
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </article>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="my-4"></div>
                                <h2 class="resume-section-title text-uppercase font-weight-bold pb-1">
                                    References
                                </h2>

                                <div class="row" style="color: #58677c;">
                                    <div class="col px-3">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li class="mb-2">
                                                <div class="fw-bold">
                                                    John Dos
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="resume-degree-org">Undergraduate - University XAV</div>
                                                <div class="resume-degree-time">Email - johndos@gmail.com</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col px-3">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li class="mb-2">
                                                <div class="fw-bold">
                                                    Rody Dos
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="resume-degree-org">Graduate - University XAV</div>
                                                <div class="resume-degree-time">Email - johndos@gmail.com</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: CV has dummy content and inside can be further improved. Problem is - if I set margin = 0 and pdf is 2 page then it spills to next page without bottom content margin.